# What is the correct order of the prior vector in fitensemble?

Tags: matlab, random-forest

When using matlabs `fitensemble` to learn a classifier I can specify the parameter `prior` as well as parameter `classnames`.

Has the order of the elements in both vectors be the same? And what is the standard value for true/false classes?

To be more specific: assume true class has prior probability 0.6, false class 0.4; Should I use:

`ens = fitensemble(...,'prior',[0.6 0.4])` or

`ens = fitensemble(...,'prior',[0.4 0.6])` or

`ens = fitensemble(...,'prior',[0.4 0.6],'classnames',[true false])` or

`ens = fitensemble(...,'prior',[0.4 0.6],'classnames',[false,true])` ?

I cannot find the answer in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/fitensemble.html).

The documentation of [perfcurve](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/perfcurve.html) is more specifc:

> **Prior**: Either string or array with two elements. It represents prior
>   probabilities for the positive and negative class, respectively.
>   Default is 'empirical', that is, perfcurve derives prior probabilities
>   from class frequencies. If set to 'uniform', perfcurve sets all prior
>   probabilities equal.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Dan. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ens = fitensemble(X,Y,method,nlearn,learners) creates an ensemble model that predicts responses to data. The ensemble consists of models listed in learners.*

**First part**

*You have to use `prior` in alphabetical order of your class labels.*

So if the labels are `['A','B']`, you use `'prior',[P(A) P(B)]`,

or if the labels are `['true','false']`, you use `'prior',[P(false) P(true)]`,

or if the labels are `[-1 10]`, you use `'prior',[P(-1) P(10)]`.

**Second Part**

About the `classnames`, this option is used so that you can call `fitensemble` for a fewer classes in your data.

Imagine you have four classes `A,B,C,D`, so your `Y` will be something like:

```
Y = [A;A;B;D;B;A;C;A;A;A;D, ... ];
```

Now you may write `'classnames',['A';'B'],` if you want `fitensemble` for just two classes and it will be the same as `'classnames',['B';'A'],`.

I know this is a late answer, I hope it helps.

**Example**

I have used 'fisheriris' database, which has three classes (`setosa',`versicolor`,`virginica`).

because it has `150` cases and `50` of each class, I randomized the data and selected `100` samples.

```
load fisheriris
rng(12);
idx = randperm(size(meas,1));
meas = meas(idx,:);
species = species(idx,:); 
meas = meas(1 : 100,:);
species = species(1 : 100,:);
trueprior = [ sum(strcmp(species,'setosa')),...
              sum(strcmp(species,'versicolor')),...
              sum(strcmp(species,'virginica'))] / 100;
```

The `trueprior = [0.32,0.30,0.38]` shows the true prior probabilities.

In the following code I have trained three `fitensembles`, first one with default options so the prior probability is `empirical` (is as same as `trueprior`); Second one is trained with `pprior` set to `trueprior` which will have the same results as the fist (because `trueprior` is in alphabetical order of class labels). The third one is trained with non-alphabetical order and shows different results than the first two.

```
ada1 = fitensemble(meas,species,'AdaBoostM2',20,'tree');
subplot(311)
plot(resubLoss(ada1,'mode','individual'));
title('Resubstitution error for default prior (empirical)');
ada2 = fitensemble(meas,species,'AdaBoostM2',20,'tree','prior',trueprior);
subplot(312)
plot(resubLoss(ada2,'mode','individual'));
title('Resubstitution error for prior with alphabetical order of class labels');
ada3 = fitensemble(meas,species,'AdaBoostM2',20,'tree','prior',trueprior(end:-1:1));
subplot(313)
plot(resubLoss(ada3,'mode','individual'));
title('Resubstitution error for prior with random order');
```

[image]

I also trained a `fitensemble` with only two classes using `classnames` option

```
ada4 = fitensemble(meas,species,'AdaBoostM1',20,'tree','classnames',...   
       {'versicolor','virginica'});
```

As a proof `AdaBoosM1` that doesn't support more than two classes works fine here with only two classes.

Comment: Odd...the ClassNames property of an ensemble should be automatically sorted then. If you could give a short usage summary in the beginning of your answer it be even more useful.

Comment: perfect. I simply used predict with an ensemble on completely random data and can confirm your results.